# All values selected in mutiple selection box not recording in MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

On this page, http://www.pfacmeeting.org/2016/phpabstracts/submit_form.php, there is a multiple selection box with 4 choices. Here is the code for that element:

```
<select id="audience" name="audience" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Newly licensed or unlicensed fiduciaries">Newly
   licensed or unlicensed fiduciaries</option>
  <option value="Experienced fiduciaries">Experienced
   fiduciaries</option>
  <option value="Attorneys">Attorneys</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

I did a test a couple of times and selected **Newly licensed or unlicensed fiduciaries** and **Attorneys**. However, in the DB field, it only recorded Attorneys. In the php file that processes the form (submit_process.php), first I capture the field to variable:

```
$audience = mysql_escape_string($_POST['audience']);
```

Then I insert it into the table:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO abstracts VALUES ('', ......'$audience','.......)";
```

The dots just represent other variables before and after audience. 
The data is recording into the field, but as I said, it is just the second choice - Attorneys. Any idea why the first choice is not recording also? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to post more code

Answer (score 1):

The multi-select post a PHP associative array so you will need to loop through the selected results of the array and insert them for each line.

```
    foreach($_POST['audience'] as $audience)
    {
      $query = "INSERT INTO abstracts VALUES ('...." 
              . mysql_escape_string($audience) . ",.......)";

    }
```

also, you need to add the array symbol in the name :

```
<select id="audience" name="audience[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Answer (score 1):

multi select produces an array.

To insert all selected in one field implode the array

```
$audience = mysql_escape_string(implode(',',$_POST['audience']));
```

oh as KAD says `name="audience[]"` is required to.

side note- `mysql_*` depreciated start moving away from it as soon as you can.

Comment: KAD/Dagon, thanks for your help. Probably not doing this right. Getting query is empty error after I submit the form.  Here's how I did it as per your suggestions:

variable declaration section:
 $audience = 
        mysql_escape_string(implode(',',$_POST['audience']));

 query section:

    foreach($_POST['audience'] as $audience) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO abstracts VALUES ('', '$date', '$title', etc, etc
    '$objectives', " . mysql_escape_string($audience) . ", $etc, etc,)";
    }
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: out strategies are mutually exclusive -mine inserts one row, KAD's multiple. we don't know which you want

Comment: I think you are mixing up both styles, can you post a clear code in the question rather than the comment to try figuring out what's wrong?